# Get current user language using javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

In CRM 2011 it's easy to get current user language using javascript, using the following code:

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid();
```

Is there anyway to do the same in server side using plugins ?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample in a Plugin:

```
class GetUserLanguage : IPlugin
{

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        //PluginSetup abstracts setup code: http://nicknow.net/dynamics-crm-2011-abstracting-plugin-setup/
        var p = new PluginSetup(serviceProvider);

        var user = p.Context.InitiatingUserId;

        var lcid = RetrieveUserUiLanguageCode(p.Service, user);

    }

    //From the SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670609.aspx
    private static int RetrieveUserUiLanguageCode(IOrganizationService service, Guid userId)
    {
        var userSettingsQuery = new QueryExpression("usersettings");
        userSettingsQuery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("uilanguageid", "systemuserid");
        userSettingsQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userId);
        var userSettings = service.RetrieveMultiple(userSettingsQuery);
        if (userSettings.Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            return (int)userSettings.Entities[0]["uilanguageid"];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options for it that I've used before.

1. Use a Retrieve on the systemuser entity using the userid from the plugin execution context. Don't forget to set the column set to just get the user! Otherwise systemuser can be a hefty retrieve for online envs.
2. Issue a WhoAmI request to the server.

I personally use the former because Retrieves are very common for devs who use plugins, but not all are familiar with the WhoAmI message (it derives from retrieve: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.whoamirequest.aspx)

Unfortunately I have not found a way to get it without issuing a request to the server.  Let me know if this helps!

Nick

Comment: Please describe how a retrieve on systemuser or WhoAmI request can get the current user language

Comment: A `WhoAmIRequest()` will not return the user's language code.

Answer (score -1):

I think that once the user selects a preferred locale you can pick it up using:

```
Thread.CurrentUICulture.LCID
```

Comment: The thread on which a CRM Plugin is running will not usually be running under the context of the calling user.

Comment: @Nicknow That’s irrelevant. If the plug-in is using calling user context then the suggested solution is far better than calling CRM each time the plug-in runs.
The request to usersetting is better suited for external applications targeting user preferences and not when running inside CRM context. 
Also, I would make the static RetrieveUserUiLanguageCode either private or public so all plug-ins can use it. 
making it protected doesn’t make sense since you’re not inheriting from GetUserLanguage

Comment: But you don't know that the plug-in is using the calling user context. The Plug-in can be executing in the context of "John Smith" even though "Jane Doe" is the user initiating the action. If you want the same result that the JavaScript in the question stated you can't rely on the Thread. It would be making an assumption that is not guaranteed - hence why your proposed solution is not supported by the CRM SDK. I changed the accessor per your suggestion - hadn't really looked at it because I was just posting it as sample code copied from the SDK.

Comment: In a plugin you can tell if you are in the calling user context or not by comparing the UserId and IntiatingUserId values in the execution context.  If they match, then the plugin is running under the calling user.